# Error creating foreign key on id_user (check data types)

Tags: sql

I have an error when I trying create FK (in phpMyAdmin) `incomes.id_user` to `users.id`
However, both have `int(11)` type. Whats wrong?

Database: `mysql-10.1.43`

Error:

```
Error creating foreign key on id_user (check data types)
```

PhpMyAdmin in `relationView` mode:

users:
[image: table 1]
incomes:
[image: table 2]

Comment: please tag with database, and show the complete error

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: What is the error and what does the SQL that creates the foreign key look like?

Comment: Perhaps the signed / unsigned type causes your problem. See the difference on the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between tables.

`id` in table users is unsigned while in table incomes, `id_user` is signed.  They need to be the same for both.